# Facebook app "usable" (public) by anyone?

Tags: facebook, settings

Is there anyway I can test an FB app without defining roles/developers/tester. I want the app to be "public" to anyone. How do I do that? Now I'm set as an administrator. I guess I could add developers, tester etc but I want the app to be usable by anyone.

I can't find the settings in my app for this (https://developers.facebook.com/apps//settings/basic/)

I'm using this fb -login from a website and it works for me, but not anyone else - which I want to.

I've googled some and found "Set the Default Activity Privacy to Public" but I cant find this setting. Am I blind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you find things when you just ask about them... If anyone stumbles upon this issue...

I found it now but it was not that obvious. I hade to enter my contact e-mail first (under menu-item Settings) and then go to menu-item "Status & Review"!? and there it was obvious what to do...

=>

### Under the app-name

Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public? Make it "Yes" and answer the question that FB has about making it public available.

Answer (score 0):

Can you any account login now?  The 3 permistion are '@"public_profile", @"user_birthday", @"user_friends"' used by me. I don't know whether is ok this method for me?

Comment: Yes, I can. Those three permissions are ok. If you define them you know you know that the user has those permissions. If you don't define them you get Facebooks default permissions which could change.